# Qt use other project as dependency

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I want to use QHttpServer in my application. I don't want to just add libs so I create git repository and add QHttpServer project as submodule. How to create project which use this QHttpServe project.

I tried to create project with subdirectories then add existing project(QHttpServer) and create new common project but i can't use classes from one project in another.

[image: screen]

[image: pro file]

[image: src added]

[image: network added]

---

I can't run my app :(. Some problem with libs

[image: problem]
[image: working]

Proper configuration
[image: proper config]

Comment: Try with `INCLUDEPATH += ../qhttpserver` followed by `DEPENDPATH += ../qhttpserver`

Comment: No change :(. I added screen

Comment: I add INCLUDEPATH += ../qhttpserver/src and new error occured :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still need to add `LIBS += -lqhttpserver` to your project. Make sure the QHttpServer project is built before your project at the subdirs project, and add `QMAKE_LIBDIR += <qhttpserver-output-dir>`.

Answer (score -1):

You have to add QtNetwork module to our project.

Add

```
QT += network
```

to `MainApp.pro` file.

I recommend reading [documentation for qmake project files](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmake-project-files.html).

Comment: I added this but then i got new error: /home/skoczo/Desktop/projekty/SmartHouse/MainApp/main.cpp:8: error: undefined reference to `QHttpServer::QHttpServer(QObject*)'. Look at last screen in first post.